# Why do we score (upvote/downvote) Questions in GIS meta?

Tags: discussion

I'm very curious about why we have scoring policy in meta exchange forum. (now you can say it belongs on the SE meta site) in gis.se we can score an answer or a question in terms of serving the purposes or its quality but in meta it is an offer and I dont understand why people gives downvote to answer.

I'd be happy if you make me informed and share your opinion.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the [meta help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) and focus on the section marked "Voting is different on meta."

Comment: thank you whuber. that is the good point for me... `members of the community may simply disagree with your bug, feature request, support issue, or the nature of the discussion.` i know that downvote is not affect main reputation but it repulse me for offering new things for community.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @whuber.

Comment: I'm glad you asked the question (+1) but am not sure why you see what is asked in meta as an offer rather than a question?  To me, main is questions about GIS, and meta is questions about how main works.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in GIS meta meta? GIS meta is for questions about GIS main :)

Comment: @Aragon I just read this [thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans) and remembered your question here. I thought it might be of your interest.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @Andre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason not directly mentioned in the FAQ is also that the meta statistics, including the main vote counts, are a very visible data point when it comes to moderator elections.

In that sense, @PolyGeo's note about lack of answers has even greater weight.

Answer (score 8):

I had not previously seen the [**meta help link**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) that @whuber provided - and it is a very useful one.

I probably exercise my downvote in meta more than in main because I know it does not affect reputation and that it helps to separate ideas that I agree with from those that I don't.

Something that I would like to see in meta, that relates to this question, is people using Answers more and Comments less to express their views, partly because it gives more room for explanation, but more so because it gives us a quicker way to gauge community sentiment on whatever issue is being discussed via votes cast.

The upvoting on comments helps, but because they do not have downvotes available, the opposing views are not so quickly distinguished in terms of community consensus.